# Set android:onClick to a Menu Item in XML - Where to put method?

Tags: android, xml

So I have a menu with 2 items set on it in res/menu/menu_item.xml. I want to add on onClick method to the Menu Item but where do I put the method? I have the menu_item set on 3 different activities but I want one universal method which is called by the onClick method in the menu_item.xml file.

res/menu/menu_item.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Household"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:onClick="myHousehold"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="About"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:onClick="aboutApp"/>

</menu>
```

This is the method which uses this XML to set the menu on each activity.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need the `onClick` and should add a method like this to enter menu item activities:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_settings:
        {
            // Here you can set your intent and start the activity
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
            this.startActivityForResult(intent1, MY_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        case R.id.profile:
        {
            // Here you can set your intent and start the activity
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override`onOptionsItemSelected` method from your `Activity` class and check `selected` item and do your operation as per your needs.

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_action_settings: {
            // Do something

            return true;
        }
        case R.id.profile: {
            // Do something

            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Create a `common` class like below:**

```
//Utils.java

public class Utils{
    Context mContext;

    // constructor
    public Utils(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return "test";
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

**Use it from all activities:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_action_settings: {
            Utils utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());
            String username = utils.getUserName();

            return true;
        }
        case R.id.profile: {
            // Do something
            Utils utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());
            utils.doSomething();

            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: So this method will need to be added to every activity that contains the options menu?

Comment: YES, you have to override it from each Activity which has option menus

Comment: Ah okay. I was wondering if there was a way to create one method that acted on all of them, hence the onClick method which I was using. Because since all activities are using the same menu file, it would have been a universal method.

Comment: You must override onOptionsItemSelected from all activity. But you can create common method for item click operation. Like when user click on profile option you can make a common method for it and use it from all activities.